# Can't use php variable from another file

Tags: php, file, variables

like my title says, whenever I try to use my variables from another php file, it doesn't work (Undefined variable). 
I did declare them in the file that I'm including. 
For example, I have this file called **variables.php** that have this in it:

```
<?php
$DEBUG = TRUE;
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "29185917-database");
$DEBUG_LOG_FILE = "../log";
?>
```

And then I have another file called **debug.php** that tries to use the variable 'DEBUG' but it cannot access it. Here is my debug.php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'variables.php';
function echo_debug(string $message)
{
    if($DEBUG) {
        echo $message;
    }
}
?>
```

Whenever I try to use my function **echo_debug** I get the error message :
Undefined variable 'DEBUG'.
Any help on this problem is appreciated :).

Comment: Functions have their own scope. The variable is accessible, just not from inside the function. In your function, right above your `if()`, try to add `global $DEBUG;` (Though it would be considerably better to pass `$DEBUG` as a parameter to the function instead of using global, but I have no idea how you are calling your function.)

Comment: you should pass the variable as a parameter. Also how do you call `echo_debug()`??

Comment: I am calling my function in my index.php (home page) as echo_debug("comment that will help me debug in dev mode");

Comment: you can alternatively use PHP's `define()`. Example: `define('DEBUG', true);` THen in the function check if `DEBUG` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions have their own scope. The variable is accessible, just not from inside the function.

You could pass `$DEBUG` as a parameter

```
function echo_debug(string $message, bool $DEBUG)
```

Then you would call it as

```
echo_debug("comment that will help me debug in dev mode", $DEBUG);
```

---

Another option is to declare `DEBUG` as a constant,

```
define('DEBUG', true);
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "29185917-database");
$DEBUG_LOG_FILE = "../log";
```

Then, in your function you would check for that constant:

```
function echo_debug(string $message) {
    if(DEBUG) { ... }
}
```

---

You could also use the `global` keyword, right above your `if()`, try to add `global $DEBUG;`.

```
require_once 'variables.php';
function echo_debug(string $message)
{
    global $DEBUG;
    if($DEBUG) { ... }
}
```

But generally the other two solutions are better, global variables are sometimes frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, would there be any better alternatives because of the $DEBUG variable being redundant?

Comment: @Trainsis I'm not sure what you mean by it being redundant?

Comment: By needing to call the variable DEBUG, it every time you want to use the function echo_debug. It would be great to store the variable at one place and just change it there.

Comment: Are you talking about if you pass the variable when you call the function? My answer outlines 3 possible solutions to your problem, the first one is the only one that I would consider "redundant", because you'd have to pass the variable every time.

Comment: Yes I am talking about that<

Comment: @Trainsis Right, so just use the 2nd method in my answer and you won't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you can also use a constant and avoid the variable issue altogether.

```
<?php
define('DEBUG', true);
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "29185917-database");
$DEBUG_LOG_FILE = "../log";
?>
```

Then in the function check if the constant has been defined

```
<?php    
require_once 'variables.php';    
function echo_debug(string $message) {
    if (defined('DEBUG') && DEBUG === true) {
        echo $message;
    }
}    
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

do like this:

```
function echo_debug(string $message,$data)
{
    if($data === TRUE) {
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

call function:

```
require_once 'variables.php';
$message = "comment that will help me debug in dev mode";
$output = echo_debug($message,$DEBUG);
print_r($output);
```